# How to tune ASP.NET CreateUserWizard?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, createuserwizard, user-registration

I have created ASP.NET WebForms site on IIS 7.5. I want to create step by step user registration. I want to store the basic and detailed information about registered users in a specially created database table (not in aspnet_users table). I want to validate email first and then prevent next registration step for the user whose email address already exists in the database. At the last registration step I want to present summary form. All previous input and select fields should be duplicated in this form with "disabled" attribute.

Please tell me how to adjust CreateUserWizard ASP.NET Control and web.config file to these needs?

Answer (score 1):

You can add steps to CUW as shown here:

[Customize CUW](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103243/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070506-1.aspx)

[Storing Additional Information](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs)

[Show Summary of user registration](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/09/22/user-details-summary-in-createuserwizard.aspx)

For verification you can set requiresUniqueEmail="true" in your [membership element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b9hw62f.aspx):

Your have several requirements in one question. It would have been better if you had split into different questions.